# How to prove for each weight, $E^{adj}_\alpha$ is non-degenerate?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Recently, I'm learning group theory, Lie algebra, as a particle physics graduate student.

---

In the simple algebra topic,
I know that by definition, we first need to find out all the commutative Cartan generators $\{H_i\}$. And in the adjoint representation (from now on denoted by mathbb), we need to find all the $|\mathbb{E}_\alpha\rangle$ which are eigenstate by all  the $\mathbb{H}_i$, action defined as commutation:
$$\mathbb{H}_i|\mathbb{E}_\alpha\rangle:=|[\mathbb{H}_i,\mathbb{E}_\alpha]\rangle=\alpha_i|\mathbb{E}_\alpha\rangle.$$
But I don't know how to prove that for each specific "vector" $\vec{\alpha}=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2...)$, with dimension equal to rank, there is only one such $|\mathbb{E}_\alpha\rangle$, in other words, it's non-degenerate for each $\vec{\alpha}$.

Or, it's equally satisfying if somebody can help prove that for each specific $\vec{\alpha}$, there is a unique linear transformation from generators $\{T_a\}$
to $\mathbb{E}_\alpha$. (Physics students only care about matrix representations.)

Thank you in advance!
Please lemme know if I didn't illustrate my question fully.

Comment: If I understand properly the first question, you want to understand why the root space relative to $\alpha$ is (at most) 1-dimensional (the word "non-degenerate" sounds strange for me though). This is not trivial but can be found in standard references.

Comment: Yes, Yes, That's exactly what I mean.  Each root only correspond to a specific $\mathbb{E}$ in the adjoint representation. "Non-degenerate" is a physics term.  If you don't have time to extract the explanation, can you refer to any source or book for me? Because I couldn't find one that's the reason I asked here.  My book (oriented for physics students) does not mention this. @YCor     Thank you!

Comment: For instance, Carter's book *Lie algebras of finite and affine type*.

Comment: This is also covered in Humphreys' Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation theory. It is Proposition 8.4(a).